# Heavy php operations in an http request, realistic? (creating lots of objects etc)

Tags: php

I developed a board game app (for android/iphone) and added a multiplayer component to it. Was thinking of using app engine (java) for the backend, so implemented that way, but turns out the cpu costs are probably going to be too high (app engine is probably not the best choice for this sort of app).

I don't have much experience with php's performance, am wondering if anyone can give me an idea if I'm heading down a bad path translating it to php. Basic steps would be:

1. Http request is made to my server, player is trying to perform a move (it's a turn-based game).
2. Fetch game state from database. This will probably be stored as a flat json string (there's not much point to creating a schema for the gamestate).
3. Deserialize json string into workable gamestate objects (like houses, cars, etc).
4. Perform gamestate manipulations finally (like moving the player's car to a new house etc).
5. Serialize modified gamestate, persist back to database.
6. Send json response back to player, which will contain updated gamestate.

I don't know if that's a lot of work to try doing in the context of a single http operation. Some numbers:

1. Expecting about 500 players using the service at any given time.
2. Each game consists of only 2 to 8 players, each game is completely independent.
3. The json gamestate object is about 25k in size when serialized.
4. The json gamestate object will have to deserialize about 300 objects to restore the complete state of the game (houses, cars, etc).

Is this unrealistic? The best solution I think would be to get a dedicated server, and just leave all the gamestates in memory, but I'm trying to get by with some of the shared hosting platforms for now. This means I have to keep going back and forth to the database to get gamestate, deserializing and serializing.

Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: "Store serialized state into a database" is a code smell, are you sure you specifically want to use the database as a key-value storage? (from your birds-eye view, I see no other obvious red flags)

Comment: Hi, yeah thought about it, the gamestate is temporary and I'd prefer being able to trash the state in a single delete rather than cleaning out rows of different parts of the gamestates. There are also no interesting use cases I can think of for keeping the gamestate broken up in diff tables / columns. The gamestate is very compact, the board game is similar to something like Stratego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds ok. You may want to consider using a NoSQL database such as MongoDB if you are just going to be storing json, but this may not be available on a shared host.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, any serious hosting company will easily be able to cope with the traffic. I just wanted to mention a couple points :

Are you sure you want to send the entire game state back and forth each time? You should be able to get away with sending only what changed... This of course depends a lot on how your game works.

The only other issue you might have to consider is lag : a server request can easily take a second or more for the whole encode/send/wait/receive/decode process. Now if your game is turn-based this probably isn't a major hindrance, but it's always something to keep in mind (also think of people who are on a slow connection, ie no 3G coverage).

In any case, you're looking pretty good right now. If I were you, I'd go and write a few tests to see how it goes. Other than that, good luck! ;-)

Comment: Sending only what's changed after the initial instantiation of the world is a smart move, as least so long as the game is asynchronously updated and doesn't have to refresh the page after each move/turn.

Comment: What I meant was only send what changed since the last communication with the server (not since initial set-up)... Having the game refresh after each turn shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty certain a shared host would cope with that traffic, in my experience most of the websites on shared hosting get hardly any traffic anyway

you can use memcache or something like that as you said, there are plenty of cheap vps options out there if you want to go down that track.

i would get it running first and get 500 people playing, then when it becomes a problem then deal with it. no point fighting a fire that hasn't started yet